# Get facebook page category list with graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How can I get fb page first level category list which is shown in [create page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/create/)?
In documentation I found `/search?type=placetopic&topic_filter=all` 
but it returns the whole list, I need only abbreviated list.